# SQL IF/EXISTS Statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, exists

i have two tables that could look like this..

**table_gb:**

```
    ID:     Author:        Email:             Login:
    1.      John Doe       john@email.com     1
    2.      Jenn Smith     jenn@email.net     1
    3.      Michael        mich@email.co.uk   0
```

**table_user:**

```
    ID:     Username:      Email:
    1.      Jenstar        jenn@email.net
    2.      Knoxvile       knox@email.org
    3.      JohnDoe        john@email.com`
```

Now what i wanted to do with this is that to make a SQL statement that pulls all fields from the table_gb and IF "Login" == 1 then i want it to go ahead and pull the username with the matching email from the table_user...

**Returning something like this..**

```
    ID:     Author:       Username:      Email:               Login:
    1.      John Doe      JohnDoe        john@email.com       1
    2.      Jenn Smith    Jenstar        jenn@email.net       1
    3.      Michael                      mich@email.co.uk     0
```

Where it basically only gets the username from the table_user but ONLY if login is set to 1
any idea? I have tried everything basically but nothing seemed to work!...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `LEFT JOIN`

```
   SELECT g.ID, g.Author, u.Username, g.Email, g.Login
     FROM table_gb g 
LEFT JOIN table_user u
       ON g.Email = u.EMail;
```

Output:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║   AUTHOR   ║ USERNAME ║      EMAIL       ║ LOGIN ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ John Doe   ║ JohnDoe  ║ john@email.com   ║     1 ║
║  2 ║ Jenn Smith ║ Jenstar  ║ jenn@email.net   ║     1 ║
║  3 ║ Michael    ║ (null)   ║ mich@email.co.uk ║     0 ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0afa/3)

Comment: Thanks alot, i don't know why i havent thought of this. However you are right, this is the simplest method :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables and then use a `CASE` expression to display the username:

```
select g.id,
  g.author,
  case when g.login = 1 then u.username else '' end username,
  g.email,
  g.login
from table_gb g
left join table_user u
  on g.email = u.email;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6f6e/4)